# Contact table for customers and employees

Tags: mysql

I have this relationship that I need to define in my database.

What would be a good way of referring contact details to my employee and to my customer in MYSQL?

I am not sure if the ||------|| is one to one or bidirectional? Which means the Employee can be searched for by contact details?

When I search for ContactDetails, phone number for example to get the Customer or Employee details

[image: Customer-ContactDetails-Employee]

**Update**

Customer would have:
customerId(PK)
maybe other fields too.

Employee would have
employeeId(Pk)
maybe other fields too

ContactDetails would have:
contactDetailsId(PK)
phoneNumber
emailAddress
other fields

I want when I search for the customerId to get the details I have in the Customer table as well as the Contact details. Same for Employee.

How should I model my tables to achieve that?

Comment: What is the difference between Employee and Customer? It seems that this is the same entity Person...

Comment: they diverge from person. they are different. have different fields

Comment: If so then treate your scheme as `Person->Customer->Details As Details1`+`Person->Employee->Details As Details2`.

Comment: can you show? Details should be one table. Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

with this structure you can find every employye that a customer has, only by querying the Customercontacts table, and only if you need more details from the other tables you join them.

edit.
with this revision  Iadded a date so that you can search for a tine frame where the customer has contact with ione of the empoyees

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customer (cid BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customerDeatails (
> cdid BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
> , cid BIGINT
> , Details TEXT
> ,  FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES customer(cid) )
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employee (eid BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CustomerContactss(
> cid BIGINT
> , eid BIGINT
> ,contactdate Datetime
> , Details TEXT
> , PRIMARY KEY (cid,eid,contactdate)
> ,  FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES customer(cid)
> ,FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES employee(eid))
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ac28739359cacfe8694f10968322ed8)*

Comment: would the customer table have a FK for the CustomerDetails in case someone searches for the customer by ID to get the CustomerDetails as well?

Comment: NO it would only have such a foeign key if everay customer has only **one** employee. The Bridge table is small has only integers and is very fast

Comment: I am sorry, is late where I am. I just edited my comment. Say i want to search for a customer by ID and when I get the Customer contacts, I want to get the  Contact details as well. The CustomerDetails you mean is CustomerContact?

Comment: I am not sure what customer details are for, that can not be held in Customercontacts or Customer it self

Comment: I've updated my post. I just does not make sense to me if i won't have a FK in Customer and Employee, how could I get ContactDetails as well when I get the rest of the details for Employee of Customer

Comment: i have seen it my point still stands, the datails aren't needed only if a customer has many different details amd i would a the bridge table with contacts, as seach in contacts, with joined tabe customer and costumerDeatisl and employee give you all information avauilable for 1 customer#

Comment: I have seen now the last 2 lines: references the customerId and EmployeeId. I will have to try it out. then i will mark the answer if ok. thank you for now